# Eclipse: Programmatically manipulate class

Tags: java, eclipse, automation

I just came across the issue that I had 10 (or so) Java classes for all of which I wanted to:

1. Add a formal parameter "String newparam" to their constructor
2. Add this as an actual parameter to the super() call to the super class constructor (thus, the result should be super(..., newparam)).

The reason is, obviously, that the common super class of those classes now has one constructor parameter more and all extending classes had to adapt.

I just can't believe that I need to do this by hand for all classes. Eclipse must have all required concepts like "constructor", "parameter" etc. in its internals. Any way to create a script for this?

I apologize if this is trivial/well known, I have to confess that I really don't know and appreciate any hints.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. you can write a simple java application to edit all your java files. open every file *.java, extract class name, insert your new parameter, .... you can do all that by regular expresssions.

Comment: I would be shocked that nobody ever tried to develop a module on eclipse to do some update like this but it could be tricky to use, especially for only 10 classes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the constructor signature of every subclass might have to be done with some kind of script. I don't think an IDE would infer the new parameter automatically in each constructor since each subclass could potentially use the new parameter differently.

Since you're using Eclipse, you can at somewhat skip your second requirement by selecting your superclass's constructor and hitting `alt+shift+c` (shortcut for refactor -> Change method signature...).

When you add the parameter via the GUI provided, all references to that constructor (such as the `super` calls in the extending classes) will be updated as well. You can even define a default value if you want.
Then if desired you can modify each extending class's constructor to also include the new parameter (by hand, sadly).

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually did never notice the "Change method signature" refactoring, so I definitively learned something new today. It won't solve the issue but goes in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for comments and answers. It currently seems that there is no (widely) known Eclipse-built-in approach to do what I want.
Which is, in short:

> Add a new constructor parameter to the super class and, at the same time, 
>     create 
>     the same parameter in the constructors of all extending classes and pass this 
>     parameter through to the super class constructor

It should be noted, however, that the function

> Add a new constructor parameter to the super class and add a default value for this parameter to all extending classes

Does work via `refactor -> Change method signature...` (thanks @Zircon).

A rather obvious solution in case you really have a lot of classes would be to write a script. A Java class was proposed by brahimfes which would have the advantage of not requiring a new language or a new working environment since my question is Java-specific. I also think that maybe a sed script could do the trick. I did, however, not try to, first, recognize the correct lines (constructor and super class constructor call, even though the second one is trivial) and, second, identify the correct position to add the parameters and, third, actually add them. Might work, I didn't try, I just have doubts about how long you would work on such a script until it works with no errors.

Now the solution I finally went for.
I realized that I always have the same key strokes (after I added the new parameter manually to the superclass constructor) in each subclass:

1. Select the constructor line.
2. Put the cursor at the and and backtrack 3 positions (parenthesis).
3. Add the formal parameter.
4. Go down one line.
5. Go to the end of this line (which always happens to be the super() call) and backtrack one position.
6. Add the actual parameter.

There are programs out there allowing to create makros of this kind, I got a trial version of one of them (I'm on a Mac) and did it this way.

Of course, this is still not actually a solution to my question and thus I won't mark this post as a solution. While I now have a makro that that relieves me of almost all typing, I still have to open each class in the editor manually, click the correct line and then fire the makro.
This program will still save me time in the future for similar requirements. But it is not what I hoped it to be, which would be some Eclipse-built-in scripting language with access to Java syntax elements for a more high-level access then regular expressions can offer.